# Oracle SQL Developer "Run" shortcuts disabled

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suddenly all my keyboard shortcuts in the "Run" menu are disabled and I have no idea why. They were working yesterday, but not today. I can click on the toolbar menu options to run these commands (Run, Trace, etc), but they key bindings don't work. I tried [this suggestion](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/01/09/oracle-sql-developer-problem-backspace-delete-button-not-working-quick-fix/) and even went so far as to re-install it. Still no luck. Anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the menu  items in Oracle SQL Developer will be active only if at least one connection is active. 
So check whether you have your connection object is active.

For more Oracle SQL Developer shortcuts [click here](http://oracle-dbms-tutorials.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned a connection to the worksheet (or file, if that's what you are trying to run)?  It's the dropdown box on the top right-hand side.

Comment: Yes I have. I can run scripts using the toolbar buttons...I just can't use the key bindings to fire those commands off. Which is frustrating since I use a keyboard 90% of the time.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your original post.  Or rather, the image you printed shows the Run *menu* all greyed out, which is a classic symptom of a worksheet/file not being associated with a connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is for **debug** and won't be enabled until you click on some code (say a Function, Procedure, or a Package)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue until I opened the procedure/function etc. with the **procedure editor** instead of as a worksheet. This is done by finding your program in the Connections explorer and opening it from there.

[image]